# linker command failed with exit code 1 xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

When I am running small app in Xcode 7 in iOS 9, I am getting linker error like  linker command failed with exit code 1 Xcode 7, would some one help me in a right way. I tried to delete temporary files from

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

I also tried clearing the "Test Host" values in the Build Settings of my "Tests" target: but it doesn't work.

Comment: if you  accidently delete any library then this type of error occurs..look in your project folder... and check if any library or 3rd party files are in red... if they are in red color...then remove them and add them again properly

Comment: i also tried clearing the "Test Host" values in the Build Settings of my "Tests" target: but it doesn't work

Comment: post your crash log here

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you forgot to add some files to tests target, that's why it's giving error.

Try this, it may help you

Click on App name from top bar near to stop button, select edit scheme

[image]

Then following window appears, in that uncheck boxes under test target

[image]

And now clean, build and check